# Error in survey package svyglm: object 'pwts' not found - is there a fix?

Tags: r, glm, survey

Similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66465401/error-with-svyglm-function-in-survey-package-in-r-all-variables-must-be-in-des), where using `survey::svyglm()` with `rescale = FALSE` resulted in the error "`Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object '.survey.prob.weights' not found`".

Now, when I use `survey::svyglm()` with `rescale = FALSE` I get a similar error, namely: "`Error in is.data.frame(pwts) : object 'pwts' not found`". Creating the `pwts` object in the global environment fixes this problem, but I don't know if assinging the `pweights` element of the `svyrep.design` object is a correct way to do it.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this an error with the `svyglm()` function?

Here's a reprex:

```
set.seed(90385863)

library(survey)
library(srvyr)
library(tidyverse)

n <- 100

# simulate data, normal predictor and binary outcome,
# baseline weight and replicate weights
dat <- tibble::tibble(
  y_binary = sample(c(0,1), size = n, replace = TRUE),
  pred_normal = rnorm(n = n),
  weight = rnorm(n = n, mean = 15),
  weight_rep1 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep2 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep3 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep4 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight),
  weight_rep5 = rnorm(n = n, mean = weight)
)

# create design object
dat_design <- dat |> 
  srvyr::as_survey_rep(
    repweights = dplyr::contains("_rep"),
    weights = weight,
    combined_weights = TRUE
  )

# svyglm with rescale = FALSE, returns error
model_y_binary <- survey::svyglm(
  formula = y_binary ~ pred_normal, 
  design = dat_design, 
  rescale = FALSE,
  family = "quasibinomial"
)

# Error in is.data.frame(pwts) : object 'pwts' not found

# create the pwts object myself, using the pweights element of the 
# dat_design object
pwts <- dat_design$pweights

# svyglm with rescale = FALSE, now it runs
model_y_binary <- survey::svyglm(
  formula = y_binary ~ pred_normal, 
  design = dat_design, 
  rescale = FALSE,
  family = "quasibinomial"
)

rm(list = "pwts")
```